# Fetch and display rest data with Backbone / Marionette

Tags: angularjs, rest, backbone.js, marionette

I'd need some help on fetching data from my server and displaying it using Marionette.

In Angular I'd do this:

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in app.people">
        {{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}

   </li>
</ul>
```

app.js:

```
var app;

app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($http) {
  app = this;
  $http.get("http://localhost:3000/people").success(function(data) {
    app.people = data;
  });
});
```

and my server on my server (express):

```
var people = [
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Bob',
    lastName: 'Blob',
    phoneNumber: '123'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'Valdemar',
    lastName: 'Ugh',
    phoneNumber: '456'
  }
];

app.get('/people', function(req, res) {
    res.send(people);
    });
```

Now, how would I get a similar result using Marionette?

I have a model (using coffeescript here in this example):

```
class Person extends Backbone.Model
```

I also have a collection:

```
class People extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Person
    url: '/people'
```

Then I'll do this:

```
people = new People
people.fetch
    success: ->
        console.log 'works ok'
        return people

    error: (data) ->
        console.log 'no success'

console.log people
view = new Views model: people
```

What I get in console.log is:

```
works ok

People {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
_byId: Object
length: 2
models: Array[2]
__proto__: ctor
```

Now, my question is how do I use this? In order to simply list people do I even need this collection or can I do it only with a model? How would I console.log the first name of all the contact on my list? And why does it show length: 0, models: Array[0] and yet there are 2 models??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hints I can provide are:

1. Your JSON has a root. Parse the data the same as what you do in Angular.

   ```
   class People extends Backbone.Collection
     # ...
     parse: (data) ->
       data.people
   ```
2. When you want to show collection, use CollectionView or CompositeView, not View. And use the collection as option, not model.

   ```
   class PeopleView extends Marionette.CollectionView

   peopleView = new PeopleView
                  collection: people
   ```

There are still plenty of things to know about CollectionView and the collection. You can read the doc for details and practice by yourself. Be patient.

Comment: I tried this parse thing but ended up getting even less of anything with my fetch.. It now says People {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
_byId: Object
length: 0
models: Array[0]
__proto__: ctor

Comment: I would actually just like to get something console.logged before applying anything to my views, that's only the second step. I'll read more about CollectionViews later, but for now I would just like to be able to fetch something to see it actually works.

Comment: @QlliOlli, the reason you see `people` blank is, you logged this object right away after `fetch`. At that moment, the server has not responded yet so the collection is blank for sure. To get the right collection for debugging purpose, console log it after success.

Comment: The better way than console.log is, expose it as global object. `people.fetch(); window.people = people`. Then you can get full info about this object no matter success or error.

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't created specifically as an answer for you, but check out this jsFiddle which is a barebones test of getting data from a REST api and displaying it in Backbone/Marionette - http://jsfiddle.net/tonicboy/5dMjD/.

The key concept you're missing is model events.  In your view, you should bind a handler to the "reset" event of your collection.  When the collection is fetched, this callback will be used to then render the data to your template. The collection is available from your view as this.collection.toJSON().

Here is the equivalent code from my Fiddle (although it's old code I was playing with while learning Backbone and not how I would do it today).  I'll try to update my Fiddle to have more 'best practices' code.

```
        myBook.bind('change', function (model, response) {
            var view = new MainView({
                el: $("#main"),
                model: model
            });

            this.region.attachView(view);
            this.region.show(view);
        }, this);
```

Comment: OP has not shown view yet. And such collection events are native in Marionette, no need to roll out your own.

Comment: I already said specifically in my answer that this is old code from when I was just learning Backbone and not how I would do it now.  The point was to illustrate the concept of model and collection events and how you hook into them to control template display.